# How do I remove a CLOSE_WAIT socket connection?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I have write a simple program using socket in C that create a connect between X86 running windows and ARM running embedded linux(consist of only Busybox and libc).Suddenly this small program could not connect the windows and linux,then I running "netsta -a" found 3 socket's state is `CLOSE_WAIT` and PID is NULL.So I try to modify “`net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_×`” but because busybox has only the basic functions that I could not using `/etc/rc.d/init.d/network restart` makes the modify  take effect.

So I want to know:

1. how to make the change take effect with Busybox?
2. how I using socket can avoid the `CLOSE_WAIT` problem?

Comment: I don't see how this is possible. `CLOSE_WAIT` means the peer has closed and TCP is waiting for the local process to close. If there is no local process TCP should close the socket itself. Are you sure you don't mean `TIME_WAIT?`

Comment: @EJP I am sure that the state is CLOSE_WAIT and the PID shows "--".

Comment: @Ezio Are you running `netstat` as `root`?

Comment: And are you sure the process has really exited?

Comment: @EJP this program is still running but the netstat shows the socket is CLOSE_WAIT and PID is "--"

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart yes,I run netstat as root.is there different between root and non-root?

Comment: So the process is still running, so it needs to close the socket, or be killed, exactly as I said in the first place. If you knew it was still running it is baffling why you've even posted the question. What netstat may or may not show in the PID column is of less interest than your knowledge that the process is still running.

Comment: @EJB Why i post is that my program using a socket with port 1200,suddenly the socket cannot connect windows and linux,then i use netstat found the socket is CLOSE_WAIT.So i want to know how to solve this problem and avoid this in the future.i have not interest on the PID if it has no help on solve this problem.And your answer said you think the state is TIME_WAIT not correct.

Comment: I've told you. Close the socket. You probably forget to close it after you got the connection failure. It's just a common or garden file/socket descriptor leak. And don't put words into my mouth. I didn't say I think it's `TIME_WAIT.` I asked *you* to *check.* And you did.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I remove a CLOSE_WAIT connection that doesn't belong to any tasks?

As we've established that the process is still running, it *does* belong to a task. We've also established that the `netstat` output was a complete red herring.

All you have to do is *close the socket.* You probably forget to close it after you got the connection failure. It's just a common or garden file/socket descriptor leak.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out: https://github.com/rghose/kill-close-wait-connections

What this script does is send out the ACK which the connection was waiting for.

This is what worked for me.